# contar días exactos que han pasado desde fecha excluyendo fines de semana

Tags: php, jquery, datetime

un saludo a todos esperando me puedan ayudar,

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación donde debo sacar cuantos días han pasado desde una fecha hasta a fecha actual, conseguí una función sencilla con datetime que me hace el trabajo exacto, me calcula el tiempo y puedo ver si han pasado horas, días, etc  pero no excluye los fines de semana, encontré otra función que calcula solo los días hábiles, y la verdad no encuentro como fusionarlas las dos, y que maneja tipos de fechas diferentes, y no soy experto en fechas con php solo conozco lo básico.

para dar un ejemplo, se registra un caso con el formato siguiente de fecha: 2018-03-02 14:05 y necesito saque el tiempo exacto desde ese momento sin contar sábado ni domingo hasta hoy si aun son las 8:00 am no debería haber contado como 1 día sino horas, debe contar 1 día a partir de hoy 2018-03-05 a las 14:06.

Agrego las funciones que encontré:

```
    function diaTranscurrido($fechaInicio,$fechaFin){
        $fecha1 = new DateTime($fechaInicio);
        $fecha2 = new DateTime($fechaFin);
        $fecha = $fecha1->diff($fecha2);
        $tiempo = "";
```

```
    //dia
    if($fecha->d > 0) {
        $tiempo .= $fecha->d;
    }

    return $tiempo;
}
```

//uso
echo diaTranscurrido('2018-03-02 14:05:20', '2018-03-05 11:34:00')
//devuelve
2
//necesito devuelva 0 porque no ha pasado 1 día hábil

función que encontré que saca la cuenta de días hábiles pero no tiempo exacto

```
    function bussiness_days($begin_date, $end_date, $type = 'array') {
    $date_1 = date_create($begin_date);
    $date_2 = date_create($end_date);
    if ($date_1 > $date_2) return FALSE;
    $bussiness_days = array();
    while ($date_1 format('w');
        if ($day_week > 0 && $day_week format('Y-m')][] = $date_1->format('d');
        }
        date_add($date_1, date_interval_create_from_date_string('1 day'));
    }
    if (strtolower($type) === 'sum') {
        array_map(function($k) use(&$bussiness_days) {
            $bussiness_days[$k] = count($bussiness_days[$k]);
        }, array_keys($bussiness_days));
    }
    return $bussiness_days;
}

//uso

    list($dia , $fecha) = explode(' ' , $caso['creado']); //
//$dia = '2018-03-05';
    $dias_habiles = bussiness_days($dia , date('Y-m-d'), 'SUM'); // hoy 2018-03-05
        foreach($dias_habiles as $fil){
            $dias_han_pasado =  $fil;
        }
    echo 'Han Pasado: ' . $dias_han_pasado . ' Días '; //imprime Han pasado 1 días
////necesito devuelva 0 porque aun no ha pasado 1 día hábil
```

en el royecto web se registran casos de un contact center, los cuales suben de nivel si no se resuelven, cada caso sube de nivel los dias de semana (lun-viern) y si solo si tienen ya las 24 horas de creados. si se creo el viernes a las 5:00pm debe subir de nivel hoy a las 5:00pm o en su defecto mañana si tiene menos de 24 horas no se sube de nivel.

Cada caso tiene su grupo de escalamiento donde se agregan los usuarios que van a gestionar ese caso, en ese grupo se especifica que usuarios lo reciben en cada nivel y el tiempo de escalamiento, puede ser 1 día o 2 días pero solo un grupo sube cada 2 días. 
el siguiente código los sube de nivel pero no eh podido excluir el sabado ni el domingo (las funciones de fechas estan mas arriba):

```
$casos = $db->query("select id , nivel, creado from casos_caso where estatus != 'cerrado' "); 

$escalamientos = $db->query("select tiempo from escalamientos order by id asc");

//tiempo los dias que se tomara el caso en subir 1 dia, 2 dias, pero generalmente 1 dia
foreach($casos as $caso){
    list($dia , $fecha) = explode(' ' , $caso['creado']);
    $dias_habiles = bussiness_days($dia , date('Y-m-d'), 'SUM');
        foreach($dias_habiles as $fil){
            $dias_han_pasado =  $fil;
        }
    $dia = diaTranscurrido($caso['creado'] , date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    echo $dia . ' ';
    echo 'Han Pasado: ' . $dias_han_pasado . ' Días ';
    if($caso['nivel'] = $time['tiempo'] ){
                $nivel = $caso['nivel'] + 1;
                $db->query(" update casos_caso set nivel =  '".$nivel."' where id = '".$caso['id']."' ");
                echo 'Caso id: ' . $caso['id'] . ' -> ';
                echo 'Subio al nivel: ' . $nivel . ' 
';
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Espero puedan orientarme por favor y muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Podrias por favor, agregar varios ejemplos de esos que estan en los bordes, y decir como queres que se cuenten?

Comment: ejemplo si registro un caso hoy a las 12:00 cuando mañana consulte a las 8:00 me debería decir que ese caso tiene solo horas de creado no 1 día

Comment: Entonces queres la diferencia en horas y dias.. no solamente en dias.. es distinto contar solo dias a contar horas y dias... en caso de que arranque en finde como queres que sea??? podes poner una tabla con ejemplos claros?

Comment: ejemplo si registro un caso hoy a las 12:00 cuando mañana consulte a las 8:00 me debería decir que ese caso tiene solo horas de creado no 1 día, si lo registro el día jueves pasado que era día 01-03-2018 a las 12pm hoy me debería de decir que ha pasado al viernes 1 a las 12pm 1 dia hoy lunes a las 12pm 2 días y no contara el sabado ni el domingo

Comment: Por favor, no agregues eso en comentarios. usa el boton [edit], escribi una tabla con ejemplos que incluya varios tipos de casos que se te ocurran que no deben fallar.